# sites/subDomain/libraries doesn't load the library files

Tags: 7, subsites, theming

My website has two sub-domains, I need to install `imageFlow` library in both of these sub-domains but for some reasons I need to replace default images of `imageFlow` (I mean `slider.png`, `button_play.png` and `button_pause.png`) library in `sub-domian1` with some images and in `sub-dmoin2` some other pictures. To do so I created folders `sub-domain1/libraries`  and `sub-domain2/libraries` and I copied the modified version of the `imageFlow` in there. But unfortunately it doesn't work and `imageFlow` is not loaded. If copy the `imageFlow` library in `sites/all` it works well but in this way the same version will loaded for all sites.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would want to keep the imageFlow library itself in the sites/all/libraries folder, then to adjust the images for each site, modify your *theme* to override the default css and images of the imageFlow library. You could do this by copying the imageflow.css stylesheet into your theme, including it, then modifying it to point to custom images instead of the imageflow default images.

This would be a little bit more standard approach than changing the imageFlow source files.

Comment: Yes you are right, I should have do this. thanks. This approach solves the problem but why sub-domains don't load their own `/libraries` folder?